# Badges without Notifications

Tags: 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7

My Galaxy S7 was just updated to Android 8 - Oreo.

I get that one of changes in Oreo is tying the App notifications to the App Badges (e.g. your "unread messages" on the app Icon).

However, it seems that if you disable app notifications, you *also* disable the badges. I would like to enable the badge for my Email application, but still have notifications disabled.

Any suggestions on how to enable this behaviour?

Thanks!